# What does Proper policy mean in RL?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I have seen the word "proper policy" in a bunch of reinforcement learning papers. Unfortunately, these papers did not provide any formal definition of what they mean by "proper policy". My guess is it might be something related to the learning rate.

I would appreciate if someone can help me better understand this notion.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give a reference to a specific paper that uses the term?

Answer (score 1):

A "proper policy" is

> A policy that has a non-zero chance to finally reach the terminal state

In some episodic problems it is possible to construct policies that cannot complete an episode. Unless ruled out in a paper, these would be counter-examples to theories of convergence etc.

Usually any $\epsilon$-soft policy (i.e. a policy with $\frac{\epsilon}{|\mathcal{A}|}$ minimum probability of any action) should be a proper policy.